# How to associate file extension with a ClickOnce application?

Tags: file-association, clickonce

I'd like to associate `.md` extension with MarkdownPad which happens to be a ClickOnce application. Its install location is something like this:

```
C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\WJN7ZLJO.V68\8565GNNM.MKR\mark..tion_976947c1e5797c10_0001.0003_8c7e66a547386856
```

(I assume that this path can change with a future update.) This seems to complicate matters as I can't just provide a path to some EXE in c:\program files...

What's the proper way to associate a ClickOnce application with some file extension?

Comment: The proper way would be You right click the file and hit open with and set a default program.

Comment: ... and if the application is not there, you click Browse and are presented with the problem in question :)